# Can't get details of custom event parameters in GA4 dashboard

Tags: custom-events, custom-dimensions, google-analytics-4

I have defined a custom event on the site having different parameters passed via this event. These parameters are also defined in custom dimensions. (GA4)

When the page loads the event is fired and all data is sent to GA4 via GTM (Google Tag Manager).

I can see all parameter in GTM Preview.

I can see event in GA4 dashboard as well in debug mode and realtime.

When I check the same event in "Engagement -> Events", I can see the event but can't see other parameters there and I can't filter out the event on parameters. All parameters as custom dimension show (not set).

I also tried GA4 Query Explorer as well and didn't find and data with those parameters, it shows (not set) as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, (not set) means that you have just created your custom dimensions and it takes 24 to 48 hours for google to update the info, at the time I am writing this, please have a look at this link [Custom parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13504892?hl=en#custom_parameters&zippy=%2Cin-this-article).

after making sure that Google Analytics has received your updates, open your analytics.google profile and log in, then from `Admin` click on the `Report`.
Next, from the `Engagement` menu, select the `Event` like in the following photo:

[image]

At the bottom of the page, you see the list of events:

[image]

Select the event name you are searching the customised dimension for it, and at the bottom of the page you can see your dimensions or parameters:
[image]